# Are kernel headers depend on processor type, vendor etc?

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux

I have downloaded the sources for a Linux kernel from kernel.org and created the header files by calling

```
make ARCH=arm headers_check
```

I have an embedded platform and ask myself if this is enough because I don't have the header files from the vendor. What are the dependencies of header files? It looks to me that header files are quite hardware specific and I expect that they depend on the CPU type etc.. Is it enough to specify the architecture just by ARCH=arm? Is it probable that a vendor of an arm system creates its own header files for a Linux kernel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a `specific ARM board in mind` for your project, you can select that `board’s defconfig`.A defconfig is the kernel’s way of storing the `default set of build settings` and then `sets the configuration` for the kernel build.

e.g.

`1)make mrproper`

`2)make ARCH=arm integrator_defconfig`

--> here above command sets `configuration` for the kernel build to the settings in the
`integrator_defconfig` file. The integrator is a device created by ARM for doing development work and is the closest thing in the ARM architecture to a generic device.

same thing can be done for others by settting their respective specific board like `versatilepb`,`vexpress`, `exynox`,...etc.

You can find default configuration in `../arch/arm/configs/` in kernel source-code.
next

3)make ARCH=arm INSTALL_HDR_PATH=dest headers_install

which installs `specific board configured header files` so that these files have information about how to `call
kernel services` that the `C libraries` use to access kernel functionality

Comment: Thanks for your detailed description!